# Shell scripting - write contents of variable to specific place in file?

Tags: shell, scripting

I have a shell script that I am working on, and thanks to SO I now have a variable with the value I need.  Now I am trying to figure out how I can place the contents of the variable into a specific place in a file.

The file looks as follows:

```
 Package: com.chrisrjones.KegCop
 Name: KegCop
 Version: 0.0.1
 Architecture: iphoneos-arm
 Description: A frontend for the Kegboard Firmware
 Homepage: http://www.chrisrjones.com 
 Depiction: http://www.chrisrjones.com
 Maintainer: Chris Jones <chris.r.jones.1983@gmail.com>
 Author: Chris Jones <chris.r.jones.1983@gmail.com>
 Sponsor:
 Section: Applications
```

Basically I want the output after the variable has been placed into the file to look like:

```
 Package: com.chrisrjones.KegCop
 Name: KegCop
 Version: 0.0.1-645
 Architecture: iphoneos-arm
 Description: A frontend for the Kegboard Firmware
 Homepage: http://www.chrisrjones.com 
 Depiction: http://www.chrisrjones.com
 Maintainer: Chris Jones <chris.r.jones.1983@gmail.com>
 Author: Chris Jones <chris.r.jones.1983@gmail.com>
 Sponsor:
 Section: Applications
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed -i -e "/Version/s/$/-$VAR/" filename
```

**EDIT:**

To replace an old version number (if there is one):

```
sed -i -e "/Version/s/\(-...\)*$/-$VAR/" filename
```

Comment: there isn't a way i can replace the three digits everytime i run the script is there because right now it's appending the build number everytime i run the script

Comment: i.e. i have Version: 0.0.1-647-647-647